# grep -v except pattern

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I want to grep -v file except pattern.

this is my file content (test.txt):

```
a
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

I want to this result:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

And `cat test.txt |grep -v "a" --exclude="aaa"` is not correctly work and return this:

```
bbb
ccc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use word boundary `\b` which matches between a word character and a non-word character.

```
$ grep -v '\ba\b' file
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

OR

```
$ grep -v '^a$' file
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

`^` Asserts that we are at the start of a line and `$` asserts that we are at the end of  a line.

Comment: if my file content is:
wax
aaa
bbb
ccc

how to get result?

Comment: could you explain your question more clearly about why you want to match those lines?

Comment: did you mean this `grep -v 'a[^a]' file` ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj `grep -v 'a[^a]' ` will that give the expceted output? Am not sure for me it selects all the lines from the file. :/

Answer (score 1):

```
$ grep -w -v "a" test.txt
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

From the man page

```
   -w, --word-regexp
          Select  only  those  lines  containing  matches  that form whole
          words.
```

Comment: if my file content is:
wax
aaa
bbb
ccc

how to get result?

Comment: `grep -w -v "wax" test.txt` ??

Comment: no. "wax" is changing. for example file content is:
wax
aaa
cac
bbb
ccc

Comment: @AliMohammadi Is there some relation between the lines you want to grep?